# Odbc parses String as Date using internalGetDate?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, odbc

I am attempting to convert a bit of code I wrote for SQL Server connections to work with an Odbc data source. I've been running into a bit of an issue with OdbcDataReader.GetValue(int) attempting to call OdbcDataReader.internalGetDate for a string field.

Here is the code I am currently using for getting the value:

```
private static void ReadRecord<T>(IDataRecord record, T myClass)
{
    .... inside loop of datarecord fields ....
        var value = record.GetValue(i);
        pi.SetValue(myClass,
            value == DBNull.Value
                ? null
                : Convert.ChangeType(value, record.GetFieldType(i)), null);
```

When I execute this against a specific 4D data table using Odbc, I get a OdbcException with no Message attached to it. The exception stack trace shows that internalGetDate was used.

```
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32 i, SQL_C sqlctype, Int32 cb, Int32& cbLengthOrIndicator)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32 i, SQL_C sqlctype)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetDate(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.DbCache.AccessIndex(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
```

I reviewed the reference source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Odbc/OdbcDataReader.cs,495) which shows that GetSqlType is executed to determine the function to call in a later GetValue() call. I wrote this code to check the SqlType of the index in question

```
var odbcdatareader = typeof(OdbcDataReader);
var method = odbcdatareader.GetMethod("GetSqlType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var type = method.Invoke(record, new object[] { i });
var typemap = odbcdatareader.Assembly.GetType("System.Data.Odbc.TypeMap");
var typemapodbctype = typemap.GetField("_odbcType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var typemapdbtype = typemap.GetField("_dbType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var typemaptype = typemap.GetField("_type", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var typemapsqltype = typemap.GetField("_sql_type", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", typemapodbctype.GetValue(type),
    typemapdbtype.GetValue(type), typemaptype.GetValue(type),
    typemapsqltype.GetValue(type));
```

The results of this check are:

```
Char, AnsiStringFixedLength, System.String, CHAR
```

Why would Odbc's GetSqlType be reporting this as a CHAR but then using internalGetDate to try and parse the data? Am I missing something obvious?

Even weirder is when I call GetString() on that index, I also get an error with internalGetDate().

```
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32 i, SQL_C sqlctype, Int32 cb, Int32& cbLengthOrIndicator)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32 i, SQL_C sqlctype)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetDate(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.DbCache.AccessIndex(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32 i)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
```

Comment: Question.. what type of database are you accessing via ODBC..? is this Sql Server..? if so then why not get away from the `System.Data.Odbc` objects and use the SqlClient data objects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was actually related to another issue in which the database server (in this instance, 4D) relates null dates as 00/00/0000 12:00:00 AM. This date cannot be parsed by DateTime and thus OdbcDataReader crashes. I resolved that first issue by catching the exception and setting my class's property to null, but that didn't resolve the underlying issue. DbCache did not cache the value because of the Exception, and due to how [OdbcDataReader and DbCache works](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Odbc/DbDataRecord.cs,122), the system has to loop over each field and get it's data. This was the underlying error. GetString was looping through 0..i and crashing on internalGetDate for i-1 field.

The resolution is.... quite ugly in my opinion, but works for my purposes.

```
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message == "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.")
    {
        pi.SetValue(myClass, null, null);
        var odbcdatareader = typeof(OdbcDataReader);
        var dataCache = odbcdatareader.GetField("dataCache",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var dbcache = dataCache.GetValue(record);
        var valuesfield = dbcache.GetType()
            .GetField("_values", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var values = (object[]) valuesfield.GetValue(dbcache);
        values[i] = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        valuesfield.SetValue(dbcache, values);
    }
    else
        throw;
}
```